# Python PIllow 2.3.0 Saving RGB-Image as TIF

Tags: python, tiff, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to save an RGB-Image as TIF. Although i'm pretty sure that TIF can handle RGB-Images, i cannot get it working.

```
import os
from PIL import Image

def main():
inFile=os.path.join("C:",os.sep,"temp","input.tif")

img=Image.open(inFile)
img=img.convert('RGB')

img.save(os.path.join("C:",os.sep,"temp","result.tif"),'TIFF')
```

However when I run this code I get the following Error

```
IOError: encoder error -2 when writing image file
```

libtiff is installed on the W7-box.

Thanks in advance